# &self move field containing Box - Move out of borrowed content

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a struct with a field containing references to other structs (that I did not define)

```rust
struct HtmlHandlebars {
    user_helpers: Vec<(String, Box<HelperDef + 'static>)>,
}
```

And `HtmlHandlebars` has to implement a function

```rust
fn render(&self, ...) -> &self
```

And in that function I would need to move the `Box` to another function. Something like this:

```rust
fn render(&self, ...) -> &self {
    let mut handlebars = Handlebars::new();
    for (name, helper) in self.user_helpers {
        handlebars.register_helper(&name, helper);
    }
}
```

But I am kind of stuck because:

- I can't move the Box references because I am borrowing `self`
- I can't copy the Box references because that struct does not implement copy
- I can't modify `&self` to `&mut self` because that causes other problems...

Maybe I am doing it completely wrong.. Is there something else I can do? What are my options?

If you need a more complete overview of the code, you can find it [here](https://github.com/azerupi/mdBook/blob/user-helpers/src/renderer/html_handlebars/hbs_renderer.rs#L55)

**PS:** I had no idea how to describe the situation in the title, feel free to change it

Comment: I would guess you're doing it completely wrong. You can't pass a borrowed value to something that takes ownership - that's the *whole point* of the borrow checker.

Comment: Yeah I know that ;) But I am not sure how I could accomplish it. I have no problem recoding it completely if it is going to make my code better. But I have no clue how I could organize my code for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've written is trying to consume the `Vec` and its elements. In general, you can iterate over `&self.user_helpers` which will give you references to the elements rather than consuming them. That is (modulo silly typos in the pattern):

```
for &(ref name, ref helper) in self.user_helpers {
    handlebars.register_helper(name, helper);
}
```

See also: [The Rust Programming Language on iterating vectors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/vectors.html#iterating).

There is a problem with that though: Handlebars needs ownership of the helpers. It may very well be that you have to create a new `Handlebars` object every time you render, but in that case you also need to be able to create all the helpers every time you create a new `Handlebars`. There is no way to take ownership of the boxes without taking at least a `&mut` reference to the `Vec`. You need at least mutable access to take the handlers out of the struct. And if you did that, you wouldn't have the handlers around for the next time `render()` is called. Depending on how configurable the set of handlers is, you could have a function that constructs the `Vec<Box<HelperDef + 'static>>` out of thin air when you need it, or you could maintain a list of callbacks that construct `Box<HelperDef + 'static>` for you.

Comment: [`register_helper` seems to take an owned `HelperDef`.](http://sunng.info/handlebars-rust/handlebars/struct.Handlebars.html#method.register_helper)

Comment: @Veedrac Just noticed that too. Ugh.

Comment: *"It seems strange to register the helpers every time you render"* Yes, I considered that, but the thing is that I also register a template and that template could potentially change between the renders. So I would need to register the template at creation of the struct. In my case that is not a problem because my cli exits after each render. But I can't assume that will be true for every use. Someone could use my code in a long running process, like a webapp. And in that case he would have to reset the renderer each time he changes the template :/

Comment: @MathieuDavid Well, if you do have to construct the `Handlebars` struct including templates and helpers again and again, then you need a way to construct the helpers again and again. Do that and construct them on demand rather than trying to store them somewhere you can't move them out of (and if you could move them, they'd be gone after the first rendering). I edited.

Comment: @delnan You are completely right, I have however no idea how to cleanly solve this situation

Comment: @MathieuDavid Where the heck do the helpers come from? Do you create them?

Comment: @delnan No the goal here is to give the ability to users to write their own helpers

Comment: @MathieuDavid Then the users need to supply a way to duplicate their helpers, or you need to change your design so that they can use one instance of your object for multiple renders.

Comment: Yeah, I think might have to change my design.. I will need to think about that. Thanks for the help anyway :)